# Using two @font-face for one class

Tags: html, css

I using CSS3's very own @font-face for a class:

**CSS:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LP';
    src: url('font/Bebas/lp.eot');
    src: url('font/Bebas/lp.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('font/Bebas/lp.woff') format('woff'), url('font/Bebas/lp.ttf') format('truetype'), url('font/Bebas/lp.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'LP';
    src: url('font/Bebas/lp2.eot');
    src: url('font/Bebas/lp2.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('font/Bebas/lp2.woff') format('woff'), url('font/Bebas/lp2.ttf') format('truetype'), url('font/Bebas/lp2.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}

.box h1 {
    font-family: LP;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box"><h1>Some Text</h1></div>
<div class="box"><h1>تکست</h1></div>
```

this font works with english text, now i want when i have a arabic or persian text (rtl text) on same class it will work with second font-face.

**that means:**

if  is english text, css began using @font-face (lp.ttf)
if  is arabic or persian text, css began using @font-face (lp2.ttf)

but both have same name for font-face. both are 'LP'
you know, it complicate to explain,

want to using 2 @font-face for h1 tag for 2 different language.
is it possible to do this via css? or jquery? or even php??

i don't know how can i do this with h1 tag! it should be h1, not a class or id.

Comment: One possible solution is to get the server to serve up a different file based on the user's language preferences. It's nice and seamless, although a bit of work. As it currently stands, you can't do what you want if the font faces have the same name, although you may be able to include an Arabic stylesheet that overrides the English font face

Comment: Combine them into a single font.

Comment: Why can't you change `font-face` name and use `LP1` and `LP2`? Add additional class to your div `<div class="box lp1"><h1>تکست</h1></div>`, `.lp1{font-family:LP1;}` and change that class depending on user select or whatever

Comment: Can i use two different font type for a certain tag like h1?
of course i can't @Morpheus , LP is a English font, LP2 is a Arabic font.

Comment: How can do this? @SLaks

Comment: I tiried this way,but doesn't work @Morpheus

Comment: i.e. `<div class="box <?php echo $selected_language; ?>"><h1>تکست</h1></div>` is not working?

Comment: It seems to me your best option is to add a class name to the page (or some container element) based on language selection. Then every selector that calls for LP, just create a second rule like `.arabic .box h1 {font-family: LP2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially, you can use the [`unicode-range`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#composite-fonts) descriptor.
With your example, you'd only have to add one line at the end:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LP';
    src: url('font/Bebas/lp.eot');
    src: url('font/Bebas/lp.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('font/Bebas/lp.woff') format('woff'), url('font/Bebas/lp.ttf') format('truetype'), url('font/Bebas/lp.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'LP';
    src: url('font/Bebas/lp2.eot');
    src: url('font/Bebas/lp2.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('font/Bebas/lp2.woff') format('woff'), url('font/Bebas/lp2.ttf') format('truetype'), url('font/Bebas/lp2.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    unicode-range: U+0600-07FF;
}
```

However, I have no idea how well this is supported by browsers. Test thoroughly.

Comment: It works, but only on IE (i have IE 10), tested on Chrome & FireFox but didn't work, but it's best answer, i'll find a way to compatible it with Chrome and FireFox. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the solution in the wrong place.  It's not your CSS that's your problem, it's your HTML.

HTML includes `lang` and `dir` attributes to indicate the language your content is in and the writing direction it uses.  You can select elements using attribute selectors.  For instance:

```
<h1 lang="en" dir="ltr">Some Text</h1>
<h1 lang="ar" dir="rtl">تکست</h1>

h1[lang=en] { ... }
h1[lang=ar] { ... }

h1[dir=ltr] { ... }
h1[dir=rtl] { ... }
```